# React песочница

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите, есть ли сайт, где можно тестить онлайн код react js, чтобы можно было поделиться этим кодом?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 5):

Уже давно стандартом для фреймвёрков считается https://codesandbox.io/. Проект создаётся на основе стандартного. Можно подключать npm-модули, можно писать код в разных файлах.

Comment: ГДЕ считается стандартом?

Answer (score 1):

Официальный [**сайт**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) реакта советует эти площадки

> #### Онлайн-песочницы
>
> Если вы просто хотите немного поиграть с React, попробуйте
> онлайн-песочницу. Например, вот простейший шаблон на [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/),
> [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/) или  [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/).

Kак по мне cамый удобный, быстрый и доступный  это `Codesandbox.io`

> Можно очень быстро создать реакт проект набрав в браузере только
> `react.new`.

Там можно создать проект как на чистом реакте, так и на `preact`, `nextjs` (ssr), `react-typescript` и на`gatsby`.

Также есть другие, менее известные площадки

- [**Bit.dev**](https://bit.dev/)
- [**Replit.com**](https://replit.com/)
- [**jscomplete.com**](https://jscomplete.com/playground)
- [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) (По какой-то причине  в момент публикация этого ответа не работает)
- [**playcode.io**](https://playcode.io/)
- [**jsbin.com**](https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output)

Comment: Наверное закрыли внутри РФ. Очень жаль, там сложены десятки тысяч полных ответов из вопросов. Остается надеяться, что со временем откроют

Comment: @Alexandr_TT абсолютно согласен. Главное чтобы еще SO не закрыли. А то катастрофа будет O.o